# I use Dart with visual studio code The method is not defined How can I solve this problem

Tags: dart, methods, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, iterable

```
void main() {
  List a = ["aa", "bbb", "ccccc"];
  Iterable b = a.iterator;

  while (b.moveNext()) {
    /*The method 'moveNext' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable'.
     
     Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method,
      or defining a method named 'moveNext'.dartundefined_method
     */

    print(b.current);
    /* The getter 'current' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable<dynamic>'.
     Try importing the library that defines 'current',
      correcting the name to the name of an existing getter,
      or defining a getter or field named 'current'.dartundefined_getter
      */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems. E.g. `a.iterator` does not return a `Iterable` but instead `Iterator`. Also, you should not write `List` since that means `List<dynamic>` in Dart which means you are loosing type information.

The easiest way is to just use `final` or `var` and let Dart automatically use the most precise type (e.g. `List<String>`):

```
void main() {
  final a = ["aa", "bbb", "ccccc"];
  final b = a.iterator;

  while (b.moveNext()) {
    print(b.current);
  }
}
```